# Java - How to create a generic class that calls an interface method?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an API that returns JSON lists of entities, such as `Gene`, `Protein`, `Resource`, etc. For example, the `Protein` endpoint returns:

```
{
    next: "/api/1.0/protein?cursor=200",
    entities: [
    {
        symbol: "TARSH_HUMAN",
        href: "/api/1.0/protein/TARSH_HUMAN"
    },
    {
        symbol: "ABL1_HUMAN",
        href: "/api/1.0/protein/ABL1_HUMAN"
    },
    ...
```

The `Resource` endpoint is exactly the same, except `symbol` is `name`.

**Solution so far**

What I'd like to do is create some sort of `EntityListSchema` that can generate such lists no matter what the entity is. Here's what I have:

```
public class EntityListSchema<T extends JsonModel> {

    private String next;

    private List<T> entities;

    public EntityListSchema(Class<T> klass, int startAt) {
        int nextInt = startAt + Constant.API_MAX_RESULTS;
        this.next = "/" 
            + Constant.API_URL + "/"
            + klass.getEndpoint() + "?" // <-- This is the problem
            + Constant.API_CURSOR + "=" + nextInt;
    }

    ...
```

In principle, each `Entity` can then just extend `JsonModel` to ensure that `getEndpoint` is available, and we're done. But I'm seeing the error:

> The method getEndpoint() is undefined for the type Class<T>

My understanding is that this error occurs because the method `getEndpoint` is not static. But if it were static (I'm using Java 8, so I can have static interfaces) I could not return the correct endpoint depending on the class.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? This would reduce a ton of duplicate code.

Comment: `Class<T> klass` doesn't represent an instance of the class, you need only change for: `T klass`

Comment: your question is actually, how do we associate metadata *per class*

Comment: @bayou.io, you may be right. I'd definitely listen to a redesign proposal if that's what you're suggesting, although it may not technically answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing an object instance and its class, for example for a string, `String.class` is the class (your `Class<T>`) and `"foobar"` is an instance (your `T` elements in the list), in this example, only `"foobar"` has `String` methods, `String.class` has `Class` methods.

My suggestion is to use some annotation here to define the "endpoint" then use [`Class#getAnnotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-)

Answer (score 2):

You had a confusion between a `Java Class` and a `Instance` of a class,

**Class** is the definition.
An **Instance of that class** is the implementation.

```
Class<T> klass
```

represents the `Class`, this doesn't represent an object `T` or an instance of `T`, it represents the `Class` itself, with te variable names, the class name, the methods name, but no his implementations:

See: [Class java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Instead of usin `Class<T>` you need to use only `T`

Learn more on [java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Here is your code:

```
public EntityListSchema(T klass, int startAt) {
        int nextInt = startAt + Constant.API_MAX_RESULTS;
        this.next = "/" 
            + Constant.API_URL + "/"
            + klass.getEndpoint() + "?" // <-- This is the problem
            + Constant.API_CURSOR + "=" + nextInt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public EntityListSchema(Class<T> klass, int startAt) {
...
    + klass.getEndpoint()
```

So `kclass` can be `Gene`, `Protein`, etc. All `Protein` instances share the same `endpoint`, so you want to call `klass.getEndpoint`.

But: the erased type of `Class<T>` is `Class`, which does not have the method. You are really looking for a *`static virtual`* method which do not exist.

There are a few ways to solve this: [registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) is one option; annotation on the class is another explained in another answer here.

But it may be simplest in your case to use an `instance method` itself, assuming you need `this.next` only when `this.entities` is not empty. If you delay assigning `this.next` then you can declare `getEndpoint` to be in instance method and you can take its value from the first element on this list. Alternatively you can initialize with the list itself:

```
class JsonModel {
    abstract String getEndpoint();
    ...
}
...
public EntityListSchema(List<T> entities, int startAt) {
    this.entities = entities;
    if (!entities.empty()) {
        int nextInt = startAt + Constant.API_MAX_RESULTS;
        this.next = "/" 
            + Constant.API_URL + "/"
            + entities.get(0).getEndpoint() + "?" // <-- This is the problem
            + Constant.API_CURSOR + "=" + nextInt;
}
```

PS BTW props for recognizing endpoint as a single word so naming it getEndpoint, not getEndPoint.